# ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a file stored every 5 mins in elastic DB index, and each line in the file contains a start and end date, I made the configuration to handle the dates and calculate 1 day on the end date, so when I added a day I faced this error.

```
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker10] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker4] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker7] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker0] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker12] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker5] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.082 [[main]>worker13] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.083 [[main]>worker6] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.084 [[main]>worker17] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of NilClass into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.084 [[main]>worker14] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.086 [[main]>worker9] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.086 [[main]>worker17] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker16] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker14] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of NilClass into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker11] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker1] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of LogStash::Timestamp into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker16] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of NilClass into String
[ERROR] 2023-04-13 13:52:37.087 [[main]>worker1] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: no implicit conversion of NilClass into String
```

The logstash configurations

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path"
    start_position => "beginning"
    mode => "read"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{DATA}%{NUMBER:SN}%{DATA}%{NUMBER:ID}%{DATA}%{WORD:Source}%{DATA}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Start_Time}%{DATA}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:End_Time}%{DATA}%{WORD:Status}" }
    }
      if "FINISHED" in [message] {
          mutate {add_field  => { "number" => 1 } } }
      if "RUNNING" in [message] {
          mutate { add_field => { "number" => 3 } }}
    date {
      match => [ "End_Time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" ]
      target => "enddate"}
    date {
      match => [ "@timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" ]
      target => "mytimestamp" }
   # mutate { rename => { "mytimestamp" => "@timestamp" } }
    mutate { convert => { "mytimestamp" => "string" } }
    ruby {
       code => "
          require 'time'
          current_time = Date.parse(event.get('enddate'))
          new_time = current_time + 86400
          event.set('enddateone', new_time.iso8601(3))"
      }
      if "ABORTED" in [message]  {
        if [enddateone] >= [mytimestamp] {
          mutate { add_field => { "number" => 4 } }}
        else {
          mutate { add_field => { "number" => 2 } }}
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the grok does not match, then the [End_Time] field will not exist. When the source field does not exist the date filter is a no-op, so the [enddate] field will not be created.

```
current_time = Date.parse(event.get('enddate'))
```

Date.parse expects a string. If the [enddate] field does not exist then event.get will return nil, and the error message is telling you that Ruby is not willing to convert that nil to a string for you.

If the [enddate] field does exist then event.get will return a LogStash::Timestamp object, and again there is no implicit conversion of that.

You do not need to use Date.parse at all.

```
ruby {
  code => '
    enddate = event.get("enddate")
    if enddate
      new_time = Time.at(enddate.to_f + 86400)
      event.set("enddateone", new_time.iso8601(3))
    end
  '
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but when I apply your configurations I got this error

[[main]>worker10] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: undefined local variable or method `enddate' for #<LogStash::Filters::Ruby:0x135054bb>
[ERROR] 2023-04-17 13:03:51.305 [[main]>worker11] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: undefined local variable or method `enddate' for #<LogStash::Filters::Ruby:0x135054bb>
[ERROR] 2023-04-17 13:03:51.306 [[main]>worker16] ruby - Ruby exception occurred: undefined local variable or method `enddate' for #<LogStash::Filters::Ruby:0x135054bb>